# Copy the records between header and trailer into a new file including header and trailer

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which has multiple headers,detail and trailer records.(fixed length)

For instance my file looks like

```
Habcd20200317
R123 abc def
R234 dfg thg
T2 2018907
Hagfd20200316
R346 adf thg
R456 tsh ahs
T3 2018937
```

Output 
File should be saved as `20200317.txt`

```
Habcd20200317
R123 abc def
R234 dfg thg
T2 2018907
```

and `20200316.txt`

```
Hagfd20200316
R346 adf thg
R456 tsh ahs
T3 2018937
```

respectively.

How can i achieve this in unix shell scripting? Please help.

Comment: Start from formatting your post correctly.

Comment: What is the header? What is the trailer? Can such text appear in the middle?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you consider `csplit`?

Answer (score 2):

Since your records have fixed length, you can use modulo arithmetic:

```
awk 'NR%4 == 1 {outfile = substr($0,6) ".txt"} {print > outfile}' file
```